# how is 'list index out of range'?

Tags: python

Execution of this code shows: `list index out of range`.

```
x= int(input("Enter the row number"))
y= int(input("Enter the column number"))
s= []
for i in range(1,x):
    for j in range(1,y):
        s[i][j]= i*j
    print s
```

Please mind that I am a complete amateur in programming hence can't help myself in basic tasks. Thanks!

Comment: because You got empty list `s=[]`  sou You cannot ask for i-th elemnt if it doesn't exists.

Comment: You used the Python 3 tag, but your code uses the Python 2 `print` syntax. Which is it?

Comment: I'd recommend exploring the lists section of a decent Python tutorial ([example](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists)).

Comment: It is Python3. Thanks for pointing it out @glibdud

Comment: You can in fact help yourself in basic tasks if you find a tutorial and work your way through it. We're not a tutoring service.

Comment: @KenWhite I have been through tutorials however they don't help in understanding nitty-gritty of a program esp. when one is completely new to the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty you are having is that you can't extend a list by assigning to a nonexistent element.

You can do what you want using a dictionary, like this, because with a dictionary you *can* invent new elements just by assigning them:

```
s= {}
for i in range(1,x):
    for j in range(1,y):
        s[i,j]= i*j
```

But if you really want a list of lists, you have to build each list up using `append()`. With `x,y == (4,5)`:

```
>>> s = []
>>> for i in range(1,x):
        s.append([])
        for j in range(1,y):
            s[-1].append (i*j)

>>> s
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

This doesn't achieve exactly what your original code was trying to do because Python lists are zero-based, and you wanted your lowest *x* and *y* index to be 1. So

```
>>> s[2][3]
12
```

With `x,y == (4,5)` you may have been expecting this matrix to have 20 elements instead of 12. The reason you get 12 is that `range(1,n)` produces a sequence of elements *up to but not including* `n`.

And if you really are programming in Python 3 then you need to write `print(s)` because in Python 3, `print` is a function not a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialised your array `s` as empty, as such any assignment will give you an out of range error. For numeric arrays you can use the following approach to initialise it:

```
x = int(input("Enter the row number: "))
y = int(input("Enter the column number: "))

s = [[0] * y for _ in range(x)]

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        s[i][j] = i * j

print s
```

For example:

```
Enter the row number: 5
Enter the column number: 3
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8]]
```

Note: Arrays in Python start with `[0][0]`, as such the last position would be `s[4][2]` which would contain `2 * 4`. You could for example add one to `x` and `y` to get the extra dimension.

Comment: This helped. Thanks a lot.